# spring security 3.1 allow user to sign and proceed to restricted pages

Tags: authentication, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security 3.1 for authentication and the login works fine.  When a user signs up, I would like the user to proceed to the restricted pages without having to login.

There are several similar questions on stackoverflow with slightly different answers and I've tried these, but nothing seems to work for me.  Here's my security configuration:

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />       
<http pattern="/login" security="none" /> 
<http pattern="/user/forgotPassword" security="none" />
<http pattern="/user/createAccount" security="none" />
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" /> 
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/defaultUrl"
        always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
</http>
```

And here's my code (after user has been created and added to the database):

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken upaToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getName(), user.getPassword());
request.getSession();
upaToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(upaToken);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(upaToken);

return "redirect:<restricted-page>";
```

Instead of being redirected to the restricted page, the login page is displayed.  What am I missing?

I would also like to avoid the call to authenticate the user.  It seems unnecessary because the user has just signed up.  But deleting it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Your sign up controller (which contains showed code) is mapped to which URL?

Comment: It is mapped to /user/createAccount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is that your /user/createAccount URL is not covered by spring security filters due to following rule:

```
<http pattern="/user/createAccount" security="none" />
```

One of Spring Security filters can automatically keep SecurityContext between requests. Instead of doing low level session manipulation it will be better to enable filter chain for /user/createAccount and permit to any user visit this URL. You can do it using following syntax:

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/createAccount" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" /> 
    ...
</http>
```

In general it is better to leave working spring security filter chain for each URL and do not rewrite their functionality by hands.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the context into the session

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
```

And if the `JSESSIONID` cookie is not set you need to set it to the session id

Comment: Thanks! Saving the context in the session was what was missing.  Didn't have to do anything with the JSESSIONID.  I guess I cannot avoid the authentication part.  Elsewhere in SO it was said that saving the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken in the Spring SecurityContext would be sufficient, but it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: it will for the current request, then when the next request comes, spring security will look for the authenticated context in session if not found will redirect back to login page