# How to deny No Session URL access in Spring security 3.2.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have migrated spring security from 2.5 to 3.2.3. If I access a URL that should redirect to login page in case of no/invalid session. At the moment, when I deploy the application on tomcat and access any URL without logging in, first time it works and redirects to login page. After first time, if I access the same URL again without logging in in a sequence, it allows the URL and application crashes. Below is my custom filter conf:

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" pattern="/**" path-type="ant" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManagerAlias">
    <sec:form-login always-use-default-target="true" default-target-url="/interceptor.do" authentication-failure-url="/login.do?code=auth" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
    <sec:session-management invalid-session-url="/login.do"> </sec:session-management>
    <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login.do"/>

    <sec:custom-filter after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" ref="securityContextFilter"/>
    <sec:custom-filter after="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="customLogoutFilter"/>
    <sec:custom-filter after="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthFilter"/>
    <sec:custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationProcessingFilter"/>
    <sec:custom-filter after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" ref="exceptionTranslationFilter"/>
    <sec:custom-filter after="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" ref="filterSecurityInterceptor"/>
</sec:http>
```

Please help me solve the issue.

Comment: After first time you get a valid session and probably therefore you can visit the page. What do you mean exactly with crashing? It eventually occurs due to another problem. May be your controller on this page needs a data from logged in sessions but can't get, because there is a user session but he is not logged in.

Comment: Yes exactly,  it crashes due to another reason. How can I avoid making of such user session ?

Comment: You should not check only if the session is valid or not you should check users role like here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17061910/954602 Clearly this works only if you assign this role to the user, after he successfully logged in.